# Create multidimensional php array from binary tree data

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, tree, binary-tree

This is what my my mysql table looks like:

```
ID      left     right    name
1       1        68       head
2       50       63       category
3       51       56       music
4       57       62       gardening
5       58       59       trees
6       60       61       flowers
7       52       53       pop
8       54       55       folk
```

I understand the concept of this binary tree, but it's to complex for me to translate this into a **multidimensional php array**.

I have found some good examples ([1](http://phpden.info/binary-search-trees-in-php), [2](https://github.com/kevbaldwyn/weatherama/tree/master/_dev/includes/dbtree)), but these examples output html and spaces to show the hierarchical order.

Comment: what your goal?